# in the my code if repeats repeatedly but but it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I press escape, in the debug it says that Pause(), Resum(), Pause() completed. And during the pause, Resum(), Pause(), Resum(), Pause() increase. During the dialogue, I press escape more to turn off the dialogue and still pause. How can I make sure that only one action is performed, and not several different ones? RETURN NOT WORKING

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused;
    public DialogWindow dialogWindow;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Debug.Log("resume");
                Resume();
            }
            if (DialogWindow.IsDialog)
            {
                Debug.Log("dialog");
                dialogWindow.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("pause");
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    } 
    public void Pause()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
    public void ToMainMenu(int sceneNumber)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `return` inside your if blocks so it won't try to evaluate the next conditions.

Comment: @Martheen its not working. I was tryed many 
location methods but not one not working

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use else if instead of just else, that would eliminate any chance of the different if statements to trigger simultaneously.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (GameIsPaused)
        {
            Debug.Log("resume");
            Resume();
        }
        else if (DialogWindow.IsDialog)
        {
            Debug.Log("dialog");
            dialogWindow.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("pause");
            Pause();
        }
    }
```